# how to convert the parameter in a list of string(using split method to split them) corresponds to a case class's parameter

Tags: scala

I have a case class, and a list of string for example, List("123:abcd")

```
object BaseSDCConfig{
  case class Whitelist(accountId: String, ruleName: String) extends BaseSDCConfig
}
```

how to convert the parameter in that string to this case class? What should I put into it, thanks!

```
val mylist = BaseSDCConfig.Whitelist()
```

Comment: That list has only one value, is that intentional, or you wanted to have two elements?

Comment: I want to use split method to split them into two value

Comment: because it's a list I need to .mkstring() and then .split() , am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex pattern to segregate and identify the two parts of the `String` and use `collect()` to weed out the badly formatted input.

```
class BaseSDCConfig
object BaseSDCConfig{
  case class Whitelist(accountId: String, ruleName: String) extends BaseSDCConfig
}

val pattrn = "([^:]*):([^:]*)".r

List("123:abcd", "id7:rule9", "no colon here", "444:xyz", "too:many:colons")
  .collect{
    case pattrn(accnt, rule) => BaseSDCConfig.Whitelist(accnt, rule)
  }
//res0: List[BaseSDCConfig.Whitelist] = List(Whitelist(123,abcd)
//                                         , Whitelist(id7,rule9)
//                                         , Whitelist(444,xyz))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! In that case, how to test that? how to mock a List[BaseSDCConfig.Whitelist]? 
Some thing like this ?"def getWhitelist(newList: List[BaseSDCConfig.DynamoDBUpdateWhitelist]) ={
    doReturn(newList).when(service).getDraxWhitelist
  }"

Comment: That's a different, and separate, question. Post a new question to get more, fresh, eyes on it.

Comment: Hi  @jwvh, if the List is only List("abcd"), the pattern is like = "([^:]*)".r, right?
case class Whitelist1(accountId: String]) extends BaseSDCConfig
List("abcd").collect{
  **
}